# Can i access device files (/dev/...) using NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

If yes, to all of them? Which permissions are needed?

Comment: That sounds like something that would be easy for you to test yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, C++ does not give you more file access than Java. Same restrictions and access permissions apply. If your code runs as root, you have full access to /dev both from Java or using NDK.